App for playing MIDI file over MIDI
I found few apps that can load and play MIDI files but in synth fashion.
I am looking for app capable to play MIDI files over MIDI -- i.e. I have digital piano (keyboard) connected to my Android phone so the keyboard/DP would be my output.
I am interested in players not apps which are capable of doing it as as "side-effect" like for example Synthesia. In other words I would like to execute "browse", "open", "play" and that's it.
